# Web fonts not rendering in IE 9 on live server, but fine when viewed locally

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I'm a graphic designer by trade and I've been working on redesigning my portfolio. In the process, I've encountered a problem with IE 9 not rendering @font-face and Google fonts on live servers. Strangely, when viewing my own site locally in IE 9, there's no problem.

This appears to be occuring universally (only in IE 9 and not in older versions in IETester), and is not isolated to my own website. For example, [this demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39519/webfontsdemo/index.html) works fines in all browsers but IE 9, which reverts to default fonts.

I've uploaded my site as it stands now [here](http://neorelic.com.au/staging/). The heading relies on this CSS from Font Squirrel:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'LeagueGothicRegular';
src:url('../fonts/LeagueGothic/League_Gothic-webfont.eot');
src:url('../fonts/LeagueGothic/League_Gothic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/LeagueGothic/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/LeagueGothic/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/LeagueGothic/League_Gothic-webfont.svg#LeagueGothicRegular') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

As with the earlier demo, this works perfectly in all browsers but IE 9. Is this a known issue? Or could it be a localised issue on my own computer? I've already tried resetting IE 9 to default settings, clearing the cache and restarting. I couldn't find any other posts with this exact issue, so I'm at a loss to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

I think this has more to do with IE's Internet Options > Security Settings. If you set the security level of the zone "Internet" to high, it shuts off web fonts. Since "Intranet" is in its own zone with a lower security level, it showed the fonts. "Medium High" is set by default in IE9 for the "Internet" zone which does support web fonts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. After playing with the security settings, this definitely appears to be the culprit. I'll have to keep this in mind. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Check that your page is not being rendered in Compatibility mode.  Turn it off and see if the fonts come through.

More info about turning off compatibility mode here.  http://www.punchakitten.com/id/forcing_ie_to_not_use_compatibility_modeever

Note: I had to turn it off at the server (HTTP header)... must have been a policy to always use compatibility mode for some reason in our Intranet zone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me in IE9, are you sure it's not a setting in your browser?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you must be right as I've now had a few other people report that it's working for them. I've just tried reinstalling IE, but that hasn't fixed the problem on my end. I'll keep searching for a solution.

Comment: do you have any add-ons installed?

Comment: No add-ons. I don't actually use IE aside from testing, so everything is default. The only solution that's worked for me is turning off Protected Mode in IE's Security settings. As this is on by default, I'm concerned that this could be a problem for a lot of visitors to my site.